# Is it necessary or useful to inherit from Python's object in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In older Python versions when you create a class, it can inherit from `object` which is as far I understand a special built-in Python element that allows your class to be a new-style class.

What about newer versions (> 3.0 and 2.6)? I googled about the `object` class but I get so many results (for obvious reasons).

Comment: If your code will also be used under 2.x, it's good to be explicit.

Comment: It's well answered in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object

Comment: Agreed; the main question is version-agnostic now, so this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You don't need to inherit from `object` to have new style in python 3. All classes are new-style.

Comment: Notice that this means all classes inherit from `object` regardless if typing an explicit `(object)` or not in Python 3.1

Comment: You don't have to, but the "Porting Python code to Python 3" says that it's still valid: http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/pyporting.html#subclass-object
Also: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes

Comment: From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9448136/7829525) mentioned in nngeek's comment, seems like a good stable reference for old-style vs. new-style (only really relevant to Py2) is: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes - the above links seemed to have since changed.

Answer (score 94):

I realise that this is an old question, but it is worth noting that even in python 3 these two things are not quite the same thing.

If you explicitly inherit from `object`, what you are actually doing is inheriting from `builtins.object` *regardless of what that points to at the time.*

Therefore, I could have some (very wacky) module which overrides object for some reason. We'll call this first module "newobj.py":

```
import builtins

old_object = builtins.object  # otherwise cyclic dependencies

class new_object(old_object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(new_object, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.greeting = "Hello World!" 

builtins.object = new_object  #overrides the default object
```

Then in some other file ("klasses.py"):

```
class Greeter(object):
    pass

class NonGreeter:
    pass
```

Then in a third file (which we can actually run):

```
import newobj, klasses  # This order matters!

greeter = klasses.Greeter()
print(greeter.greeting)  # prints the greeting in the new __init__

non_greeter = klasses.NonGreeter()
print(non_greeter.greeting) # throws an attribute error
```

So you can see that, in the case where it is explicitly inheriting from object, we get a different behaviour than where you allow the implicit inheritance.

Comment: It's relevant because in general the expectance is that the behaviour is equivalent. It isn't equivalent, hence my observations.

Comment: Don't you just hate it when someone deletes their comments so it looks like you're talking to yourself?