# Error: "x instance has no attribute y" when trying to inherit from class

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes, instance

I can't really understand what I'm doing wrong, since when I try it in "small scale" and it is working there.

I have a class named `Play()`

I goes like this:

```
class Play():
    def __init__(self):
        file = open("/home/trufa/Desktop/test", "r")
        self.word = random.choice(file.readlines()).rstrip()
        self.errAllowed = 7
        self.errMade = 0
        self.errList = []
        self.cheatsAllowed = 2##chetas not incrementing
        self.cheatsMade =0
        self.wordList = ["*"]*len(self.word) ##this one is the one I want to have available in another class
```

...

Then I have another class called `Score()`

```
class Score(Play):
    def __init__(self):
        self.initialScore = 0

    def letterGuess(self):
        self.initialScore += 1
        return self.errList
```

...

I instantiated both:

```
game = Play()
points = Score()
```

And if I do:

```
print points.letterGuess()
```

It gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trufa/workspace/hangpy/src/v2.py", line 188, in <module>
    startGame()
  File "/home/trufa/workspace/hangpy/src/v2.py", line 134, in startGame
    print points.letterGuess()
  File "/home/trufa/workspace/hangpy/src/v2.py", line 79, in letterGuess
    return self.errList
AttributeError: Score instance has no attribute 'errList'
```

I don't understand why since I can do this without any trouble:

```
class One():
    def __init__(self):
        self.list= [1,2]

class Two(One):
    def meth(self):
        return self.list

uan = One()
tu = Two()

print uan.list 
print tu.meth() ## Both output [1,2]
```

I'm very new to OOP so I could be doing all kinds of silly mistakes but I can't figure out where!

I **think** I have posted all the relevant code, but I you think the error might be elsewhere, I can provide it.

<sup>As I said I'm very new, so this might have nothing to do with inheritance I just think it called that when you get "something" from within another class (you must be shouting at the screen by now)</sup>

Comment: Are you able to do `return Play.errlist`?

Comment: @Matt: He isn't, as that class doesn't have a class variable of that name.

Comment: `print tu.meth() ## Both output [1,2]` don't do meth. drugs are bad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You overwrite the original `__init__`, which is then never called and doesn't initialize the members. You must call the parent's `__init__` separately, usually with this snippet:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(Score, self).__init__()
```

See the [docs for `super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) for details. However, `super()` only works for so-called new-style classes. You must therefore either change the definition of `Play` to inherit from `object`:

```
class Play(object)
```

or you call the parent's method directly:

```
def __init__(self):
    Play.__init__(self)
```

Comment: To further clarify, you must inherit from `object` in 2.x. In 3.x, [old-style classes go away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238606/is-it-necessary-or-useful-to-inherit-from-pythons-object-in-python-3-x), so inheriting from `object` is unnecessary.

Comment: @senderle: True, thanks. I should start to respect 3 more and not take it as given, that 2.x is used.

Comment: I haven't yet understood how to use `super()`, wasn't [this](http://pastie.org/1977636) what you suggested.

Comment: @Bolderwyn, I'm struggling to do that myself -- hence the comment. :)

Comment: @Trufa: no, I made the same mistake, when I first started to use it. The first argument to super() is *the own class*, in the pastie example, `Two`. Think of it this way: super() *returns* the super-class of its first argument.

Comment: By the way, in this way you can also call methods of super-super-classes all the way up the inheritance chain. If One inherits from Zero and isinstance(self, Two), `super(One, self).__init__` is the method of the class Zero.

Comment: @Boldewyn: No I'm even more confused! :) you say like this? `def __init__(self):
        super(Two, self).__init__()` (I say that what you suggest is in the docs, but I'm not figuring out somthing)

Comment: @Trufa, I wrote a long comment that wound up reproducing what Bolderwyn has already said. So I'll just add that this is why I suggested getting used to inheritance before trying to use `super`. :)

Comment: Read this just the other minute via delicious: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Comment: @senderle: I am actually using you method, but just trying to understand that for later. Thank for all the help!

Comment: @Boldewyn: hmm ok but its not working that, way. I'm confused... I'll take another shot at it but I'll have @senderle 's advice in mind.

Answer (score 4):

When you inherit from the class `Play`, you automatically get the attributes that you've created in the *definition* of `Play`, but you don't get the attributes that you've created in `Play.__init__`. You have to explicitly call it like so:

```
class Score(Play):
    def __init__(self):
        Play.__init__(self)
        self.initialScore = 0
```

See [Boldewyn's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143693/error-x-instance-has-no-attribute-y-when-trying-to-inherit-from-class/6143744#6143744) for using `super` to do this; but IMO you should probably get used to the basic way inheritance works before fiddling with `super`.

To further clarify, if you don't override `__init__` as you have in this case, then it's inherited and called automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sure this is obvious, but you have to learn it at some point I guess :) +1 for first and correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize the superclass.

```
class Score(Play):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Score, self).__init__()
    self.initialScore = 0
```