# how to avoid repeated calls to init when passing a subclass to inherit in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, radix

consider class

```
class Grid():
    def __init__(self,r,z,t):
        self.rgrid = r
        self.zgrid = z
        self.tgrid = t
        self.otherstuff = long_computation(r,t,z)

class Solution(Grid):
    def __init__(self,r,g):
        self.zones = r
        Grid.__init__(self,g.r,g.z,g.t)

g = Grid(my_r,my_z,my_t)
sol = Solution(r,g)
```

This creates what I want, except the "long_computation" is done twice. What would be a clean way to structure the classes that would work whether I called just Grid, or whether I also did the Solution step?

Thanks, J.

Comment: Why does `Solution` inherit from `Grid`, and why does it take an existing `Grid` as an argument instead of `r`, `z`, and `t`?

Comment: what's the difference between `r` in `Grid.__init__` and in `Solution.__init__`? it seems like last one should be named `zones`

Comment: You can have a class variable `done_long_computation` which you'd set the first time `__init__` is executed, and `__init__` checks if `done_long_computation` is set.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a method to perform calculation in parent class. Using this you can call the method and compute the stuff which takes long time when you want to calculate it.

```
class Grid():
    def __init__(self,r,z,t):
        self.rgrid = r
        self.zgrid = z
        self.tgrid = t

    def start_long_computation(self):
        self.otherstuff = long_computation(self.rgrid,self.tgrid,self.zgrid)
```

call the `start_long_computation` in Solution instance

```
class Solution(Grid):
    def __init__(self,r,my_r ,my_z ,my_t):
        self.zones = r
        Grid.__init__(self, my_r ,my_z ,my_t)
        Grid.start_long_computation(self)
```

You can now access `otherstuff` using `self.otherstuff` in Solution instance

or

```
class Grid():
    def __init__(self,r,z,t):
        self.rgrid = r
        self.zgrid = z
        self.tgrid = t

    def start_long_computation(self):
        return long_computation(self.rgrid,self.tgrid,self.zgrid)

class Solution():
    def __init__(self,r,g):
        self.zones = r
        self.otherstuff = g.start_long_computation()

g = Grid(my_r,my_z,my_t)
sol = Solution(r,g)
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to for Solution to know if otherstuff has been created already? Sometimes I will want to use Grid and have it run the long-computation without calling it as part of Solution. Sometimes I will want to call Grid without calling Solution. Maybe subclass() ... hm. I just saw __dict__.keys()

Comment: You can use self.__dict__ to see if the attribute exists for the class and calculate if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

- IMO you should avoid any computations inside of `__init__` and only do attributes assigning, so if you wanna do `long_computation` once and use its result you can do it outside of `__init__` and pass as argument.
- If you are not using *Python 3* you probably should inherit you base class `Grid` from [`object`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#object) type (in *Python 3* all classes are inherited from `object` [by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1238632/5997596)). And there is function named [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) and you [probably should use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python) like `super(Solution, self).__init__` (or just `super().__init__` in *Python 3*) instead of writing `Grid.__init__`.
- Passing `Grid` instance to initialize `Solution` object looks ugly, why not passing required `Grid` attributes? Also your example will not work since `Grid` objects doesn't have `r`, `z`, `t` fields, but `rgrid`, `zgrid`, `tgrid`. If you need to construct `Solution` instance from `Grid` you can write custom constructor (e.g. there are many of them in [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) type).

Considering all this remarks

```
class Grid(object):
    def __init__(self, r, t, z, otherstuff):
        self.rgrid = r
        self.tgrid = t
        self.zgrid = z
        self.otherstuff = otherstuff


class Solution(Grid):
    def __init__(self, zones, r, t, z, otherstuff):
        self.zones = zones
        super(Solution, self).__init__(r, t, z, otherstuff)

    @classmethod
    def from_grid(cls, zones, grid):
        return cls(zones, grid.rgrid, grid.tgrid, grid.zgrid, grid.otherstuff)


otherstuff = long_computation(my_r, my_t, my_z)
g = Grid(my_r, my_t, my_z, otherstuff)
sol = Solution.from_grid(r, g)
```

Comment: Thanks, for pointing me to super() ... and then discovering mysteries of old-style classes vs new. The classmethod device is also new to me and will be useful.  In some more detail, my "otherstuff" is more like two dozen values: grid.o1, grid.o2, grid.o3, grid.o4, grid.o5,..... etc. I don't want to have to type all of those in the main code each time. But I can use the classmethod to keep the main code clean. Appreciate the update.

Answer (score 0):

The quick, dirty way would be to add a "new" parameter to the initialization:

```
def long_computation(r, t, z):
    print "Oh, the despair of wasted time!", r, t, z

class Grid():
    def __init__(self,r,z,t, new_grid=True):
        self.rgrid = r
        self.zgrid = z
        self.tgrid = t
        if new_grid:
            self.otherstuff = long_computation(r,t,z)

class Solution(Grid):
    def __init__(self,r,g):
        self.zones = r
        Grid.__init__(self, g.rgrid, g.zgrid, g.tgrid, False)
        # Inherit long computation from parent.
        self.otherstuff = g.otherstuff

my_r = 77
my_z = 18
my_t = 6.2
r = 0.333

g = Grid(my_r,my_z,my_t)
sol = Solution(r,g)
```

Another possibility is to memoize `longcomputation`.

Does that help at all?  I know it's not aesthetically satisfying, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, this looks pretty ugly but builds on the above:

```
class Grid(object):
    def __init__(self,r,z,t):    
        self.rgrid = r
        self.zgrid = z
        self.tgrid = t       

        if "otherstuff" not  in self.__dict__.keys(): 
            self.otherstuff = self.long_computation(r,t,z)
        else:
            print "No Need to Call"

    def long_computation(ggg,r, t, z):
        return 123456

class Solution(Grid):
    def __init__(self,r,g):
        self.zones = r

    if "otherstuff" in g.__dict__.keys(): 
       self.otherstuff = g.otherstuff

    super(Solution, self).__init__(g.rgrid,g.zgrid,g.tgrid)
```