# Save changes of state for custom class instances in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree

I'm having a hell of a hard time trying to figure out why my `print(Node(3).value)` is printing `0`. Any ideas?

When I run this code, I get

```
First: 6 Value: 8 Children: [9]
First: 8 Value: 23 Children: [9]
First: 3 Value: 3 Children: [5]
First: 6 Value: 8 Children: [7]
First: 4 Value: 20 Children: [8]
First: 1 Value: 17 Children: [8]
First: 8 Value: 23 Children: [10]
First: 5 Value: 11 Children: [8]
First: 1 Value: 17 Children: [2]
0
```

Any ideas? I know I'm not saving the Nodes anywhere but my mind can't wrap around it.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
# Complete the primeQuery function below.
n = 10
first = [6, 8, 3, 6, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1]
second = [9, 9, 5, 7, 8, 8, 10, 8, 2]
values = [17, 29, 3, 20, 11, 8, 3, 23, 5, 15]
queries = [1, 8, 9, 6, 4, 3]


class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, value=0):
        self.data = data
        self.value = value
        self.children = []

    def addChild(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def setValue(self, givenV):
        self.value = givenV


def primeQuery(n, first, second, values, queries):
    i = 0
    while i < n - 1:
        f = Node(first[i], values[first[i] - 1])

        s = Node(second[i], values[second[i] - 1])

        f.addChild(s.data)

        print(f"First: {f.data} Value: {f.value} Children: {f.children}")

        i += 1

    print(Node(3).value)


primeQuery(n, first, second, values, queries)
```

Comment: you are not saving your `Node` objects `f` & `s`

Comment: `Node(3)` will create a `Node` with `value = 0`.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov , Oh duh! Um, but I'm a little confused on how to actually save them?

Comment: @KlausD. , Yeah, that makes sense seeing my code. But is there a sample snippet on how to save objects?

Comment: it depends on what data structure you are trying to build

Comment: @AzatIbrakov A general tree I believe.

Comment: do you want to create `Node` once and then expect that they will be re-used if they've been already created?

Comment: Yeah exactly @AzatIbrakov

Comment: `data` supposed to be unique identifier of node?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov , That's what I was trying to do yeah. SOrry it's not clear :(

Comment: in case where `Node` already exists but we're passing different `value`, should it be changed using `setValue` method or remain unchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement

```
Node(3).value
```

creates `Node` object with `data` set to `3` & `value` set to `0` (default argument), so when you're getting its `value` it returns `0`.

If you want to create `Node` objects and then re-use them -- you should store them in some sort of container.

Assuming that

- `data` field is a hashable unique identifier of `Node`,
- if `Node` has been created and we're passing different `value` -- old `value` persists

I see at least 2 approaches here:

- Create container on the top level, explicitly add `Node`s to it upon creation and access them using it afterwards like

  ```
  def primeQuery(n, first, second, values, queries):
      i = 0
      # top-level container of ``Node``s
      nodes = {}

      def get_or_create_node(data, value):
          try:
              # trying to access already created ``Node``
              result = nodes[data]
          except KeyError:
              # no ``Node`` found, create it...
              result = Node(data, value)
              # ... and register
              nodes[data] = result
          return result

      while i < n - 1:
          f = get_or_create_node(first[i], values[first[i] - 1])
          s = get_or_create_node(second[i], values[second[i] - 1])

          f.addChild(s.data)

          print(f"First: {f.data} Value: {f.value} Children: {f.children}")

          i += 1

      print(nodes[3].value)
      # we can return ``nodes`` here if we want to use them outside of given function
  ```

  gives us

  ```
  First: 6 Value: 8 Children: [9]
  First: 8 Value: 23 Children: [9]
  First: 3 Value: 3 Children: [5]
  First: 6 Value: 8 Children: [9, 7]
  First: 4 Value: 20 Children: [8]
  First: 1 Value: 17 Children: [8]
  First: 8 Value: 23 Children: [9, 10]
  First: 5 Value: 11 Children: [8]
  First: 1 Value: 17 Children: [8, 2]
  3
  ```
- Extension of previous approach: restrict `Node`s creation using global function which caches already created ones:

  ```
  # in module namespace
  def get_or_create_node(data, value=0,
                         *,
                         # hack, see **note**
                         cache={}):
      # we've moved class definition inside of a function to restrict its instances creation
      class Node(object):
          def __init__(self, data, value):
              self.data = data
              self.value = value
              self.children = []

          def addChild(self, child):
              self.children.append(child)

          def setValue(self, givenV):
              self.value = givenV

      try:
          result = cache[data]
      except KeyError:
          result = Node(data, value)
          cache[data] = result
      return result
  ```

  (**note**: here we're using "hack" with mutable default argument, more info may be found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158294/good-uses-for-mutable-function-argument-default-values))

  Then everywhere when we need to create/access `Node` object -- we should use this function only like

  ```
  def primeQuery(n, first, second, values, queries):
      i = 0
      while i < n - 1:
          f = get_or_create_node(first[i], values[first[i] - 1])
          s = get_or_create_node(second[i], values[second[i] - 1])

          f.addChild(s.data)

          print(f"First: {f.data} Value: {f.value} Children: {f.children}")

          i += 1

      print(get_or_create_node(3).value)
  ```

  this will give us the same output as before.

## Further improvements

### changing `value`

If our assumption about `value` being persistent turns out to be wrong -- we can simply add changing of `value` if it was passed like:

- in first approach:

  ```
  def get_or_create_node(data, value):
      try:
          # trying to access already created ``Node``
          result = nodes[data]
      except KeyError:
          # no ``Node`` found, create it...
          result = Node(data, value)
          # ... and register
          nodes[data] = result
      # adding ``else``-clause
      else:
          result.setValue(value)
      return result
  ```
- in second approach: set `value` parameter's default value to `None` and check if it was specified like

  ```
  def get_or_create_node(data, value=None,
                         *,
                         cache={}):
      class Node(object):
          def __init__(self, data, value):
              self.data = data
              self.value = value
              self.children = []

          def addChild(self, child):
              self.children.append(child)

          def setValue(self, givenV):
              self.value = givenV

      try:
          result = cache[data]
      except KeyError:
          if value is None:
              # default value
              value = 0
          result = Node(data, value)
          cache[data] = result
      else:
          if value is not None:
              result.setValue(value)
      return result
  ```

## inheriting from `object`

If we're working in **Python 3** -- there is no need to specify `object` as base class, it will be set by default (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238606/is-it-necessary-or-useful-to-inherit-from-pythons-object-in-python-3-x)), so instead of

```
class Node(object):
    ...
```

we can simply write

```
class Node:
    ...
```

### use `for`-loop instead of `while`

We don't need to use `while`-loop & increment `i` by hand when we have `for`-loop and `range` objects, so instead of

```
i = 0
while i < n - 1:
    ...
    i += 1
```

we can write

```
for i in range(n - 1):
    ...
```

also I think here is a typo, because we're skipping case with `i` equal to `n - 1`, so we can fix it:

```
for i in range(n):
    ...
```

finally we can see that there is no need in `i` index when we can use [`zip` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) & iterate over pairs of `first` & `second` `list`s elements like

```
for first_data, second_data in zip(first, second):
    f = get_or_create_node(first_data, values[first_data - 1])
    s = get_or_create_node(second_data, values[second_data - 1])

    f.addChild(s.data)

    print(f"First: {f.data} Value: {f.value} Children: {f.children}")
```